# How can i combine multiple array into a single array

Tags: php

```
$selectRst = $clntobj->runSelect($selectQry,$dbcon);        
$noncntrctDetails = $selectRst->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($noncntrctDetails as $value)
{
    foreach($value as $key => $val)
        {   
        $valArray = explode(",",$val);
        //$output = array_combine($key,$valArray);
        print_r($output);
            //print_r($valArray);                   
            /* $valArray = explode(",",$val);
            $valarr =[$valArray];
            print_r($valarr); */
            // $tarray = array_merge()
            //$totalArray = array_push($valArray,);
            //print_r($totalArray);
        }
}
```

Comment: you tried array_merge?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: What was the reason for downvote? Elaborate on your question.

Comment: yes,tried array merge,i have 4 arrays that all from for each,how can i implement.Because of if i use array merge,i should have four array that all are diff name.here i have one variable...How it is possible..

Answer (score 0):

To combine multiple arrays into a single array can be down by using the `array_merge()` function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Example:

```
$finalArray = [];
$array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$array2 = ['1', '2', '3'];
$finalArray = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cnt_titles] => 8852,8854,9060,9196
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cnt_titles] => 11115)

    [2] => Array
        (
            [cnt_titles] => 11115,11834,99488
  )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [cnt_titles] => 11115,11834
        )

)....where how can i take all values in single array...

Comment: Did you put array_merge inside the foreach? If so, don't. Store the arrays, and then use it outside the foreach. E.g. `print_r(array_merge($selectRst, $noncntrctDetails));`

Comment: Within the foreach, each iteration it runs through, you're setting the values for `$valArray`. Therefore, you will only get the last instance of it. You can either use array_push(), to push the value onto the array or use `$valArray[] =` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge 2 multidimensional arrays into one multidimensional array, you use `array_merge()` to put them both in one multidimensionnal array, and then do this :

```
$arrayMerged = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
$myFlatArray = []
foreach($arrayMerged as $row) {
    foreach($row as $item) {
        $myFlatArray[] = $item;
    }
}
```

This way, you'll have your "two-level" multidimensionnal array in a "one-level" multidimensionnal array.

Basically, instead of having an "array of arrays of arrays" you'll have an "array of arrays" (I don't really know how to say it any other way, sorry ^^)